# Getting a generator on a null value after select gives no error

Tags: jq

Consider this example:

```
echo null | jq '[{"a": null}, {"a": [1]}][] | select(has("a")?) | .a[]'
```

It gives no error on the first value, but this one does:

```
echo null | jq '[{"a": null}, {"a": [1]}][] | .a[]'
```

It seems that nothing should change, because all values in the array satisfy the filter in the `select` expression.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: `echo null | jq '[{"a": null}, {"a": [1]}][] | .a[]?'` seems to work.

Comment: Maybe the error that occurs is back-propagated, and eventually caught by `?` if present, even though  at that point there was no error yet. See: `jq -n '1? | .[]'` vs `jq -n '1 | .[]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @OguzIsmail suggested, it's a bug. I believe it's already been reported as https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1859

See in particular the first contribution by ravron in April 2019 (!), and the followup by nicowilliams.

Recall that `E?` is shorthand for `try E catch empty`, hence the title of the bug report:
"try/catch catches more than it should"

It's as though the `catch` clause is misplaced:

```
try (select(has("a")) | .a[]) catch empty
```

In cases like this, comparing the results with those obtained using gojq can be helpful.

Comment: Hey, congrats on 100k

Comment: @OguzIsmail - Time flies!